# how do I center the anchor tag inside a div whose parent is working as an overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css

what I want is to center the anchor tag texts vertically also I want the "contents" div to fit the screen so that if the screen gets smaller or bigger the anchor tag doesn't run off the margin creating overflow which I don't want, I tried a bunch of different ways to fix this but none seem to work, any help is appreciated! here's the code...

```js
$(function() {

  $(".menu-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".menu-overlay").toggleClass("open");
    $(".menu").toggleClass("open");

  });

});

$('.menu-link').click(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
});
```

```css
.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 5%;
}

#brandname {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Circular Std Black;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  right: 5%;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
}

.menu-link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-line {
  background-color: white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-line-2 {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu-line-3 {
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-1 {
  transform: translateY(7.5px) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu.open .menu-line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-3 {
  transform: translateY(-7.5px) translateY(50%) rotate(45deg);
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-circle {
  background-color: #E095F0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu:hover .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.menu.open .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(60);
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-overlay {
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity:0;
  display:hidden;
}

.menu-overlay.open {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity:1;
  display:block;
  z-index: 1001;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.no-scroll{
    overflow: hidden;
}


/***********anchor tag************/
.contents {
    display: table;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.contents a{
    display: table-cell;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Circular Std Book;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <div id="brandname">Test</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <span class="menu-circle"></span>
      <a class="menu-link">
        <span class="menu-icon">
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-1"></span>
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-2"></span>
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-3"></span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-overlay">
        <div class="contents">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>
    </div>


</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to the `.menu-overlay.open` identifier:

```js
$(function() {

  $(".menu-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".menu-overlay").toggleClass("open");
    $(".menu").toggleClass("open");

  });

});

$('.menu-link').click(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
});
```

```css
.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 5%;
}

#brandname {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Circular Std Black;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  right: 5%;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
}

.menu-link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-line {
  background-color: white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-line-2 {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu-line-3 {
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-1 {
  transform: translateY(7.5px) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu.open .menu-line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-3 {
  transform: translateY(-7.5px) translateY(50%) rotate(45deg);
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-circle {
  background-color: #E095F0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu:hover .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.menu.open .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(60);
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-overlay {
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity:0;
  display:hidden;
}

.menu-overlay.open {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity:1;
  z-index: 1001;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


.no-scroll{
    overflow: hidden;
}


/***********anchor tag************/
.contents {
    display: table;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.contents a{
    display: table-cell;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Circular Std Book;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <div id="brandname">Test</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <span class="menu-circle"></span>
      <a class="menu-link">
        <span class="menu-icon">
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-1"></span>
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-2"></span>
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-3"></span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-overlay">
        <div class="contents">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>
    </div>


</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when I'm adding flexbox to "contents" or "menu-overlay .open" as @Arfizur Rahman mentioned above, everything is working fine except the elements of the navbar(anchor tag being invisible) are working without opening the menu from the left side of the menu, any fix and why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using `flexbox`:

Here's the `CSS` to achieve what you want:

```
.menu-overlay.open {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1001;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.contents {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.contents a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Circular Std Book;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: when I'm adding flexbox to "contents" or "menu-overlay .open" everything is working fine except the elements of the navbar(anchor tag being invisible) are working without opening the menu from the left side of the menu, any fix? – Zeniel 8 mins ago